# Can a preposition be used before "that"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, clauses, adverbial-phrases, adjective-phrases, pied-piping

Can a preposition be used before "that"?
For example:
**The house in that I live is nice**

or maybe: 
**The house that I live in is nice**

I think which is correct in these cases but why? Could someone explain me?

Comment: Idiomatically, you can't "front" the preposition to come before ***that***. You can do it with *The house **in which** I live is nice*, but otherwise it has to be *The house **that I live in** is nice*.

Comment: but isn't "which" used for non-defining relative clauses? And why the second is correct?

Comment: No, not in relative clauses. However, there are a few prepositions that license complement clauses: "I'll go **provided that** you pay!" "I was lucky **in that** there was little real competition".

Comment: @BillJ: I'm not sure, but I think 2-300 years ago you could use ***for that*** to mean ***in order that, because*** (as in *I study hard for that I will get a good job*). Certainly not today though.

Answer (score 1):

The following choice is correct.  "That I live in" serves as an adjectival phrase, restricting "house".

> The house that I live in is nice.

The following choice is incorrect:

> The house in that I live is nice.

"In that I live" is correct for expressing a different meaning.  "In that I live" is an adverbial qualifier similar to "As long as I live" or "Inasmuch as I live".  The following example is grammatically correct.  Notice that "in that I lived" describes what makes the house "nice", not the "house" itself:

> The house is nice, in that I lived through the earthquake.  Some of my neighbors died when their apartment buildings collapsed.

Comment: if "in that I live" is an adjectival phrase then what is "in which I live" ? Is it describing the house or me ? I really got confused now

Comment: @BoSsYyY "In which I live" is a relative clause modifying "house. "I live in x house".

Comment: @BoSsYyY -- The first quarter of your comment is incorrect.